Having trouble adding folly(fbvector) to my visual studio code mingw64 project
I've been trying to replace std::vector with folly::fbvector, but after adding Folly to my includes, I keep getting errors:
G:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: Temp\ccAhru6W.o:(.rdata$.refptr.MallocExtension_Internal_GetNumericProperty[.refptr.MallocExtension_Internal_GetNumericProperty]+0x0): undefined reference to `MallocExtension_Internal_GetNumericProperty'
G:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: Temp\ccAhru6W.o:(.rdata$.refptr.mallctlbymib[.refptr.mallctlbymib]+0x0): undefined reference to `mallctlbymib'
G:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: Temp\ccAhru6W.o:(.rdata$.refptr.mallctlnametomib[.refptr.mallctlnametomib]+0x0): undefined reference to `mallctlnametomib'
G:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: Temp\ccAhru6W.o:(.rdata$.refptr.mallctl[.refptr.mallctl]+0x0): undefined reference to `mallctl'
G:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: Temp\ccAhru6W.o:(.rdata$.refptr.nallocx[.refptr.nallocx]+0x0): undefined reference to `nallocx'
G:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: Temp\ccAhru6W.o:(.rdata$.refptr.sdallocx[.refptr.sdallocx]+0x0): undefined reference to `sdallocx'
G:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: Temp\ccAhru6W.o:(.rdata$.refptr.dallocx[.refptr.dallocx]+0x0): undefined reference to `dallocx'
G:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: Temp\ccAhru6W.o:(.rdata$.refptr.sallocx[.refptr.sallocx]+0x0): undefined reference to `sallocx'
G:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: Temp\ccAhru6W.o:(.rdata$.refptr.xallocx[.refptr.xallocx]+0x0): undefined reference to `xallocx'
G:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: Temp\ccAhru6W.o:(.rdata$.refptr.rallocx[.refptr.rallocx]+0x0): undefined reference to `rallocx'
G:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: Temp\ccAhru6W.o:(.rdata$.refptr.mallocx[.refptr.mallocx]+0x0): undefined reference to `mallocx'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status


I'm not sure what I'm missing. I'm much more skilled at coding my own libraries than integrating others, so any help would be greatly appreciated! If you need more details, just let me know.
I have done the typical adding folly to my include path and replaced all my std::vectors to folly ones.
I have also tried linking the jemalloc library which doesn't change anything.
